# int => Weekdayname

Tags: c#

Is there some inbuilt function to return weekdayname based on value 1-7?

/M

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames
```

[more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.daynames%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes and the week starts with sunday :)

Comment: @PoweRoy That depends on your CurrentCulture. I bet it's israeli

Answer (score 5):

for integers from 1 to 7, you'll need to subtract 1 as the array is zero-indexed.

```
for(int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[i-1]);
}
```

This will give localised weekday names based on the current culture.

Answer (score 3):

An even shorter way, it turns out there's a built in `enum` for this purpose:

```
Enum.GetName(typeof(DayOfWeek), weekDayNumberHere)
```

But I wouldn't use it for sites needing globalization

Comment: Even better - `((DayOfWeek)weekDayNumberHere).ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DateTime dateValue = new DateTime(2008, 6, 11);
Console.WriteLine(dateValue.ToString("dddd"));    // Displays Wednesday
```